# Kendo UI Notification passing array of data

Tags: kendo-ui

Is it possible to pass an array of data to [show](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/notification#methods-show) method so it's rendered in the template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the array a property of the object:

```
notification.show({data: ["Foo","Bar","Baz"]}, "info");
```

Then your template would like this;

```
  <script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
      <div class="new-mail"><ul>
      # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
          <li>#= data[i] #</li>
      # } #
      </ul></div>
  </script>
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/utOxE)**

Comment: I didn't understand the question :( You won

Comment: @StefanoMagistri    I understood OP wants one notification with a list in the template, you understood multiple notifications from an array. I guess we will see what OP was looking for... ;-)